# Function $f:X\to X$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

"We have function $f:X\to X$. We know that $f$ is injective but it is *not* surjective."

Is it even possible?
If function is injective if $f(x_1)=f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$, which means that each $x$ from domain gets different $y$ from range. If the function is not surjectve then we know that not all elements from the range are "used". Which at least for $X$ does not make sense because the cardinality of domain and range is the same as $X$ is both domain and range.

Are there any mistakes in my thinking? Does this depend on whether the set is finite or infinite?

Comment: X must be infinite in order for there to be a non-surjective yet injective map from X to X.

Comment: Your thinking seems to ignore the very definition of what "infinite" means. A set is infinite if and only if there is a *proper* subset with the same cardinality as the whole set.

Comment: Google Hilbert’s Hotel and you will find  some nice examples that will help you think about infinite sets and their possible mappings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible for infinite sets. As an example consider $f \colon \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(n) = 2n$.